# Searching through a list in Python using a for loop and showing what from that list was found

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have been making a simple Blackjack game in Python and I have found a way of randomly picking a card from a list and then searching for different letters and numbers. This adds up the score for each card so the user doesn't have to do it themselves. This would look like this:

```html
card1 = random.choice (all_possible)

    all_possible.remove(card1)

    add_face = set('JQK')
    for faces in card1:
        if add_face & set(faces):
            user_cards +=10
```

That's the simple part which I have figured out by searching on Google. I have the same thing written out for each number 2-10 which would add the corresponding number to the total score. My question is how could I search for all 2-10 in one set and add the number that was found.

An example that I tried getting to work is this:

```html
card1 = random.choice (all_possible)

    all_possible.remove(card1)

    add_face = set('23456789')
    for faces in card1:
        if add_face & set(faces):
            user_cards += ???????
```

The problem is I do not know how to end the code so that it adds the appropriate number that it found.

Comment: How did you define the `score` of each card? And what did you wanna `add up`?

Comment: How about `try: user_cards += int(face) except: pass`? Or use a dictionary, mapping the face strings to scores. This might be the cleanest solution IMHO.

Comment: @LittleQ I am trying to add up the score for each card in blackjack. Ace = 1; Jack, Queen and King = 10; 2-10 = corresponding number. This would tell the player their card score without them having to work it out. My method works but is very long.

Comment: @tobias_k I've only just started learning to code so could you please explain how I would adapt this into my code?

Comment: learn about [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) @NorbertD

Answer (score 0):

Since the scores for the cards from 2 to 10 are just their values, you can just try to convert the card's value to an integer and add that to the score. For the face cards, you can use a dictionary, mapping e.g. `Q` to `10`. You can also combine those two approaches:

```
values = {'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10, 'A': 1} # score per value
hand = ["SA", "H10", "DK", "C8"] # all the cards in a hand
score = 0 # running score
for card in hand:
    suit, value = card[0], card[1:] # separate suit and value
    try:
        score += int(value) # handes cases 2 - 10
    except ValueError:
        score += values[value] # cases J, Q, K, A
```

Note, however, that according to Blackjack rules, the ace can either score 1 or 11 points, depending on the situation, so you might want to handle the ace separately.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this my fault. card1 is a card from the deck formatted in this way: Suit+Number/face  ,  e.g. 2 of spades = S2

Comment: And all_possible is a list of every possible card that the user can get, once that card is picked it is removed from the list

Comment: I have inserted two print command lines so the code shows me what card was drawn and what the new score is, it is showing me that if card1=S2 then the score is 29. Also, I replayed it several times and it looks like the score is always 29

Comment: @NorbertD That's because I changed it to loop over an entire hand; if you want to check just the score of one card, that should be easy to change, but then you do not need a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the problem. It was much easier than I thought. Thanks for all your answers as they helped me redo my code but I found a much easier solution which is exactly what I used earlier but tweaked slightly:

```html
card1 = random.choice (all_possible)

    all_possible.remove(card1)

    add_face = set('23456789')
    for faces in card1:
        if add_face & set(faces):
            user_cards = float(user_cards) + float(faces)
```

As you can see above the 'faces' variable was the one which stored the number that was found so if I added it to the end, it would work. I have tested this and it works but if you think I'm wrong then please tell me, as I'm still learning to code in Python and I would like to learn more.

Thanks again for your help!!